# Xamarin Forms, Grouping Realm

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm, grouping

I am using Xamarin forms (.NET Standard project), Realm & MVVM Light and I need to group a list of objects based on the Initial of the last name so that I can display a jumplist within a listview.

I am having a problem when trying to group a RealmObject. I have a model like so...

```
public class Participant : RealmObject
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string RegistrationCode {get; set;}

    //More properties skipped out for brevity
}
```

Based on [this link](https://montemagno.com/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping/), I also have a Grouping class like so...

```
public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Key { get; private set; }

    public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Key = key;
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

In my viewmodel, I am able to fetch the Participants (i.e `IQueryable<Participant>`) like so....

```
var participants = RealmInstance.All<Participant>();
```

I would now like to be able to group this by Initials of the last name for which I do the following:

```
var groupedParticipants = from participant in participants
                          group participant by participant.LastName.Substring(0, 1) into pGroup
                          orderby pGroup.Key
                          select new Grouping<string, Participant>(pGroup.Key, pGroup);
```

which throws the below exception:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Realms.RealmCollectionBase' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The property type IGrouping cannot be expressed as a Realm schema type

I have looked around but unable to find working examples of grouping Realm sets. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm does not support Linq's `GroupBy` (or Select-based projections).

A workaround would be to take a Realm-based sorted query to a standard `List` and then perform your Linq GroupBy.

#### Example (using James Montemagno's Monkey project):

```
var realmSort = r.All<Monkey>().OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
var sorted = from monkey in realmSort
                 orderby monkey.Name
                 group monkey by monkey.NameSort into monkeyGroup
                 select new Grouping<string, Monkey>(monkeyGroup.Key, monkeyGroup);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also came across the link below that confirms your response....

https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/api/linqsupport.html